# Python Google Cloud Storage Connector Unit Test

Tags: python, unit-testing, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, storage

I've developed the following connector in python for google cloud storage:

```
from google.cloud import storage


class StorageConnector:
    
    @staticmethod
    def download_as_string(bucket_name: str, source_blob_name: str):
        return (
            storage.Client()
            .bucket(bucket_name=bucket_name)
            .blob(blob_name=source_blob_name)
            .download_as_bytes()
            .decode("utf-8")
        )
```

I want to do unit testing. I've implemented the following test but it seems to be uncorrect:

```
import unittest
from unittest.mock import patch

import google.cloud.storage
import mock
import requests

from six.moves import http_client

PROJECT = "PROJECT"
BUCKET_NAME = "BUCKET"
BLOB_NAME = "BLOB"

class StorageConnectorTest(unittest.TestCase):

    @patch("google.cloud.storage.Client")
    @patch("google.cloud.storage.Bucket")
    @patch("google.cloud.storage.Blob")
    def test_download_as_string(self, BlobMock, BucketMock, ClientMock):
        from my_custom_package.gcloud.connectors.storage._storage_connector import StorageConnector

        self.assertIs(ClientMock, google.cloud.storage.Client)
        self.assertIs(BucketMock, google.cloud.storage.Bucket)
        self.assertIs(BlobMock, google.cloud.storage.Blob)

        source_blob_name = "source_blob_name"
        data = bytes("This is the content of source_blob_name".encode(encoding="utf-8"))

        BlobMock.return_value = data
        self.assertEqual(
            StorageConnector.download_as_string(bucket_name=BUCKET_NAME, source_blob_name=source_blob_name), data
        )
```

Because I get the error:

```
======================================================================
FAIL: test_download_as_string (tests.gcloud.connectors.storage.test_storage_connector.StorageConnectorTest)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/unittest/mock.py", line 1325, in patched
    return func(*newargs, **newkeywargs)
  File ".../package/tests/gcloud/connectors/storage/test_storage_connector.py", line 91, in test_download_as_string
    self.assertEqual(
AssertionError: <MagicMock name='Client().bucket().blob()[47 chars]424'> != 'This is the content of source_blob_name'
```

How can I do unit testing to fully cover the code?

Thanks